# SVG path positioning

Tags: html, css, svg, path

I am making face SVG. Unable to set eyebrow on proper place. Please advice.

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path d="M10,20 Q25,10 40,20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `transform` attribute to position the path, like

```
transform="translate(50,80)"
```

Make sure you don't use **px**

Other transformations like `scale` or `rotate` are also available. [See the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace).

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(9, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(40, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. it's so easy :)

Answer (score 7):

You may use `g` element and add [translation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) (useful if you will have more path to move at the same time):

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <g transform="translate(40,20)">
  <path d="M10,20 Q25,10 40,20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Or simply translation on `path`:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path transform="translate(40,20)" d="M10,20 Q25,10 40,20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
</svg>
```

Here is the full SVG with both eyebrow (translation for both using `g` and then translate the 2nd one relatively to `g`). With this configuration you have to simply adjust the translation of `g` element if want it upper of lower

```css
svg g {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg:hover g {
  transform: translate(10px, 15px);
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <g transform="translate(10,20)">
  <path d="M10,20 Q25,10 40,20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
  <path transform="translate(30,0)" d="M10,20 Q25,10 40,20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
  
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining with different methods :)

Comment: @vaishalikapadia welcome :) but a question : why the other answer which was a simple copy of mine got accepted and not mine which is more elaborated :) is there any issue with this ? [you are free, but simply want to know if there is any issue with it so i can improve it]

Comment: No, There wasn't any issue with your answer. I am new at SVG, and not friendly with values use in path d=. Tayyab modified path values too. That made my code easy. Nothing else. 
Please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/48162219/8169957

Comment: @vaishalikapadia i could have also modified the path value too :) but it wasn't in the question so i simply replied to the question ;) as if i did something else it would irrelevant to the question because this will also be a ressource for new comer and future people and it's about positionning the SVG :)