# Eyebrow raising animation with SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg, path

I am trying to animate eyebrows with SVG. But got stuck as I am not getting proper tutorial showing the meaning and use of numbers used in `path=""` (please share a tutorial link if you know any). Anyone please help me with raising the smiley's eyebrows. 
Here is my code

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(9, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" id="eyebrow1"/>
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(40, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" id="eyebrow2"/>
 </svg>
```

I was trying with following. Sorry for bad code :P

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(9, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" id="eyebrow1"/>
  <animateMotion 
          xlink:href="#eyebrow1" 
          dur="1.2s" 
          fill="freeze"
          calcMode="spline"
          keyTimes="0; 0.5; 1"
          keySplines="0 0 1 1;
                .42 0 .58 1;"
          path ="M30, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20"
          />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(40, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" id="eyebrow2"/>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `animateTransform` since you are using transform for you path and you have to specify the type (here you can use translate) and the `from` and `to` in order to specify the start/end point of animation:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(9, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" id="eyebrow1"/>
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(40, 17)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" id="eyebrow2"/>
  
 <animateTransform 
      xlink:href="#eyebrow1"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="translate"
      from="9 17"
      to="9 22" 
      dur="2s"
      begin="0s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
       <animateTransform 
      xlink:href="#eyebrow2"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="translate"
      from="40 17"
      to="40 22" 
      dur="2s"
      begin="0s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
 </svg>
```

And as I described in my previous answer ([SVG path positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151772/svg-path-positioning/48151850#48151850)) for your question, you can use `g` element to be able to animate them both at the same time:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="35" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <ellipse cx="65" cy="45" rx="4" ry="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <g transform="translate(10,20)" id="eyebrow">

  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
  <path d="M16, 20 Q27, 10 35, 20" transform="translate(30,0)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5px" />
  
  </g>
  
  <animateTransform 
      xlink:href="#eyebrow"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="translate"
      from="10 15" 
      to="10 22" 
      dur="2s"
      begin="0s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      fill="freeze" 
      />
</svg>
```

Here is some useful links :

https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/135-three-ways-animate-svg/

Comment: Thanks @temani this is I was searching for:) Thanks for tutorials. It is helpful for me. Accepting your answer and its worth it ;)